# Permission bit of 730 for a directory? what does this mean?

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I know its `rwx-wx----` but what does `-wx` for the group mean? Can they write and execute the file but not see them? Can they overwrite file with same name or delete the file?

Comment: The best way to learn this kind of thing is by playing with it yourself.  I upvoted the question (it *is* a good question), but strongly recommend you don't *just* read the answers you get—set up some simple test cases to see for yourself what the permissions do.  (You could use `chmod 300` for your test cases for simplicity and not have to create a group.)

Comment: man chmod should help. Be wary the permissions can have different meanings for files and directories. You can have groups in Unix, and different people assigned to groups, say a group of developers.

Answer (score 2):

If it applies to a directory, then the members of the group can `chdir` to that directory and add new files, but cannot list the content.

Comment: can the group edit the file if filename is known? or would it get overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

For directories, `r` permission means that you can get a list of directory entries (i.e. the names of files & subdirectories that it contains).  `x` means you can access files or subdirectories by name.  `wx` means that you can add or remove directory entries by name (i.e. add or delete files & subdirectories).  (`w` without `x` doesn't allow anything.)

So a directory with `-wx` means you can do everything but get a list of the directory entries.  (Of course, access to individual files and subdirectories is still governed by their own permission bits.  However, remember that you don't need any permissions on a file to delete it, only write permission on the directory.)